# C++Builder 10.2 - Debugging breakpoints not working for my BPL IDE-package

Tags: delphi, debugging, c++builder

I'm trying to debug an IDE *design-time* package in **C++Builder 10.2 Tokyo** and although the package itself works, I can't get no breakpoint to work:

Just **no** blue markers and only **red'x'es** when double clicking in the editor *breakpoint* column...

---

The project options I set for *Debug*:

Debugger → Host Application: *C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin\bds.exe*

Debugger → Parameters: *-rNameOfMyBpl*

C++ Compiler → Debugging → Debug information: *True*

C++ Compiler → Debugging → Debug line number information: *True*

C++ Compiler → Optimizations → Disable all optimizations: *True*

C++ Compiler → Optimizations → Generate fastest possible code: *False*

C++ Linker → Full Debug information: *True*

Delphi Compiler → Optimization: *False*

Delphi Compiler → Use debug .dcus: *True*

---

When manually triggering a breakpoint by

```
{ _asm { int 3 } }
```

it breaks and the IDE switches to assembly view, so what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just to be clear - are these options for your package or your project using your package? If it is your project it is irrelevant if your package has been compiled without debug information.

Comment: if you got the C++/Pascal source code for the package in your project then it should work (in that case its a bugged IDE and you need to force recompile/relink/rebuild sometimes mowing the `#pragma hdrstop` line or changing order of includes help). In case you got only binaries of the package then only assembly will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments, but it seems to be a bug in RAD Studio

https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16491?filter=-2